# Staring (K)Ubuntu works only in recovery mode

Tags: 20.04, updates, kubuntu

my system was running fine till Wednesday (9 Dec). After some updates over the day, i restarted my system and I was not able to start it normally.
I can start normally from the recovery menu, other wise after grub I just see a black screen. Pressing the power-button results in shutting down(sometimes while shutting down i can see the kubuntu logo).

I assumed I have to just to backroll the updates I installed, but that have not changed anything.
The list of updates I did on that day. I restarted the pc around 19 o'clock.

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 2020-12-09 |grep upgrade
2020-12-09 12:45:06 upgrade parted:amd64 3.3-4 3.3-4ubuntu0.20.04.1
2020-12-09 12:45:06 upgrade libparted-fs-resize0:amd64 3.3-4 3.3-4ubuntu0.20.04.1
2020-12-09 12:45:07 upgrade libparted2:amd64 3.3-4 3.3-4ubuntu0.20.04.1
2020-12-09 12:45:07 upgrade flashplugin-installer:amd64 32.0.0.453ubuntu0.20.04.1 32.0.0.465ubuntu0.20.04.1
2020-12-09 12:45:07 upgrade linux-firmware:all 1.187.4 1.187.6
2020-12-09 17:25:22 upgrade curl:amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4
2020-12-09 17:25:22 upgrade libcurl4:amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4
2020-12-09 17:25:22 upgrade libcurl3-gnutls:i386 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4
2020-12-09 17:25:22 upgrade libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4
2020-12-09 17:25:22 upgrade python-lxml:amd64 4.5.0-1 4.5.0-1ubuntu0.1
2020-12-09 19:31:11 upgrade libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 2.0.2ubuntu0.1 2.0.2ubuntu0.2
2020-12-09 19:31:11 upgrade apt:amd64 2.0.2ubuntu0.1 2.0.2ubuntu0.2
2020-12-09 19:31:13 upgrade apt-utils:amd64 2.0.2ubuntu0.1 2.0.2ubuntu0.2
2020-12-09 19:31:14 upgrade python-apt-common:all 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.1 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2020-12-09 19:31:14 upgrade python3-apt:amd64 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.1 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2020-12-09 19:31:14 upgrade apt-transport-https:all 2.0.2ubuntu0.1 2.0.2ubuntu0.2
```

So I use Kubuntu 20.04 with additional PPA: wineHQ, steam, spotify, kisak-mesa
I had used the PPA Oibaf before, but since the i386 build was missing i changed to kisak-mesa, deactivating Oibaf. I also tried Oibaf again, since the I386 are working again, did not change anything so I installed the newest version of kisak-mesa again (which updated today, but did not change anything.)
In recovery mode it will try to install broken or missing packages, which are not shown after I boot into Kubuntu.

```
root@$USer$-Tower:/home/$USer$# dpkg --configure -a
root$USer$-Tower:/home/$USer$# apt-get update
OK:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease
OK:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                             
OK:3 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                            
OK:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                        
OK:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                   
OK:6 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                        
Holen:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]        
Holen:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24,2 kB]
Holen:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [56,5 kB]
Es wurden 190 kB in 1 s geholt (164 kB/s). 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
root@$USer$-Tower:/home/$USer$# apt-get install -f
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
root@$USer$-Tower:/home/$USer$# apt-get dist-upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
```

---

Edit

Okay after the comment I found at the the ampgpu driver are gone. And the fail to be build on kerne- version 5.4.0-56-generic and 5.4.0-58-generic.
So it is just the missing display-drive...

---

Edit 2
I post the code on pastbin to manage the length of this message.

dmesg https://pastebin.com/etYDiLPs

python kernlog https://pastebin.com/NsGJXW6e

python syslog https://pastebin.com/32jRBgqf

python failog is emtpy (just one or two newline feeds)

Comment: can you give us the output of these commands: `dmesg` and `python3 -c "print('\n'.join(open('/var/log/kern.log','r').read().splitlines()[-300:]))"` and `python3 -c "print('\n'.join(open('/var/log/syslog','r').read().splitlines()[-300:]))"`
and `python3 -c "print('\n'.join(open('/var/log/faillog','r').read().splitlines()[-300:]))"`

Comment: 1. What video card?  2.  Are you able to start with `nomodeset`?

Comment: The Video Card is on of the Radeon RX 570/580/590. I will test to boot option. 
Yes with `nomodeset` I can boot up again.

Comment: @LucaRavasio sorry i removed the output eaarlyer, but i do not see how it can help

Answer (score 0):

The Answer seems quiet simple, but really annoying..

```
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.6.20.906300-1164792
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.20.906300-1164792 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-56-generic 5.4.0-58-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-56-generic
FireERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-56-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.20.906300-1164792/build/make.log for more information.
```

Without the amdgpu hardware driver, I can not solve it. But i haven't notice that there was an issue.